# Problems moving wordpress site to plesk - error 404

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

Imported my site into wordpress 3.5.1, the page does show eventually, but with no CSS.

Can anyone pease help:

http://tinyurl.com/cd3l3or

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

reinstalled the sites and they work fine! Thanks!